# WeightedData Problem

Tags: list-manipulation, probability-or-statistics

I have two lists, the first one containing energies the second corresponding weights, which I want to combine into a weighted data set by using WeightedData.

```
    emu =     {6.07554,6.75035,6.01235,2.64212,1.20845,0.467369,0.38045,7.17174,2.60847,6.8873,1.29288,3.46793,0.724271,8.8205,8.42026,2.89836,2.01046,7.80828,3.2274,10.2535,2.23425,2.5784,2.23205,5.60826, \[CenterEllipsis]39372\[CenterEllipsis] ,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}

   w =        {0.000187777,6.6735*10^-7,0.0000141254,0.00029926,0.000187454,0.000198866,0.000028403,0.000225412,0.0000410494,4.83498*10^-7,4.90761*10^-8,0.000188634,0.000175243,0.000277206,0.000922494,0.0000276259,0.0000296997,0.0000281182,0.0000585339,0.000261283,0.000159857,0.0000141163,3.93197*10^-6,0.0000918486,3.02746*10^-8,0.0000943955,6.51029*10^-8,0.0000591572,0.000102857,-0.0000190349,0.0000449394,0.0000234642,0.0000112653,0.000387695,0.000152116, \[CenterEllipsis]39350\[CenterEllipsis] ,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
```

Then I say
         ew = WeightedData[emu, w]
and get an error message:

WeightedData::wtmsg: The argument {0.000187777,6.6735*10^-7,0.0000141254,0.00029926,0.000187454,0.000198866,0.000028403,0.000225412,0.0000410494,4.83498*10^-7,<<31>>,0.000210445,0.0000179127,0.0000806435,0.000426889,0.0000355587,0.000556132,0.0000220848,1.30042*10^-7,0.000421571,<<39370>>} is not a valid weight specification.

What is going wrong?

Comment: In the two list I detected  `\[CenterEllipsis]`???

Answer (score 1):

found the error: some very few elements of w were negative and Mathematica does not not seem to like negative weights.

Comment: Besides *Mathematica* lots of folks don’t like negative weights.